# exam, headrule of first page is different to second?

Tags: header-footer, exam

I define a header in the preamble:

```
\pagestyle{head}
\runningheadrule
\header{xxx\\ xxx\\ xxx}
{}
{xxx\\ xxx\\ Seite \thepage von 8}
```

Page one is diffrent to the other pages, and I don't know why :-( I am missing the underscore in page 1? Do you have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will! In this case the document class that you use may well be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\runningheadrule` puts a rule under the header for all pages from the second on. To have the rule on the first page also, you need `\firstpageheadrule`. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\pagestyle{head}
\firstpageheadrule% rule on first page header 
\runningheadrule% rule on other pages' header
\header{xxx\\ xxx\\ xxx}{}
{xxx\\ xxx\\ Seite \thepage\ von 8}

\begin{document}

test\newpage
test

\end{document}
```

An image of the reult with rules on all pages:

[image]